# PyObject_AsReadBuffer porting

Tags: python, c++, porting

As we know, `int PyObject_AsReadBuffer(PyObject *obj, const void **buffer, Py_ssize_t *buffer_len)` has been changed from v2.5, which used an `int*` type for `buffer_len`.
If I want program porting from v2.4 to v2.7, is there any problem if I just replace `int` by `Py_ssize_t`?

sample:
v2.4

```
    int bufferLength = 0;
    const void* buffer = NULL;
    PyObject_AsReadBuffer(pyObj, &buffer, &buffer_len);  //pyObj is assigned in somewhere
```

v2.7

```
    Py_ssize_t bufferLength = 0;
    const void* buffer = NULL;
    PyObject_AsReadBuffer(pyObj, &buffer, &buffer_len);  //pyObj is assigned in somewhere
```

Where can I find the source code of this function?

Answer (score 0):

No problem, just replace `int` with `Py_ssize_t` and you are good to go.